# Function cannot find most recent .zip file in Downloads folder

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

Trying to write a program and part of it is to find the most recent zip file in the Downloads folder.  Wrote a function and when I attempt to call it, I get an error that says it cannot find the file specified, yet it still references the most recent zip file in my downloads folder:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'CaseBuilderHistReport.1.31.2023.03.15.16.zip'

`def copy_latestfile():
#Get downloads folder path
#downloads_folder_path = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
downloads_folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Downloads')

```
    #Define the copy location
copy_location = '/Documents/Python/UCX Portal - Walmart/Data'

#Get list of files in the download folder
files_in_dir = os.listdir(downloads_folder_path)

#Get only zip files from download folder
zip_files = [file for file in files_in_dir if file.endswith('.zip')]

#sort the list of files based on the date the file was created
sort_files = sorted(zip_files,key=os.path.getctime)

#get the most recent file and store it in a variable
latest_file = max(zip_files)

#copy the most recent file to the destined working location
shutil.copy(latest_file)
```

`

Comment: On a coding logic note, you're not pulling `latest_file` from `sort_files`.

Comment: Try to use `latest_file = sort_files[-1]` to get the last element in list instead `max(zip_files)` which returns last file by name.

Comment: I still get the same error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'CaseBuilderHistReport.1.31.2023.03.15.16.zip'